# Unable to build docker file using jenkin pipeline

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have a Dockerfile on Gitrepo as below:

```
FROM nonprod.registry/oi-0024789/jwstc9rhel7
RUN /usr/bin/curl -kv -fsSL -o /opt/tomcat/app1/webapps/snoop.war 
https://artifactory.trusted.private.com/mw-snapshots/snoop.war
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD [ "/opt/tomcat/app1/bin/start_container.sh" ]
```

I have a jenkin pipeline code as below:

[Jenkins pipline code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvE4r.png)
I am getting an error credentials not provided to clone the git repo.

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on j***
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Cloning Git)
[Pipeline] git
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress -- 
https://stash.trusted.private.com:8443/scm/mw.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status 
code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://stash.trusted.private.com:8443/scm/mw.git/'

ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```